# Is ploticus working with macos m1 ; how to put it in the path?

Tags: path, apple-silicon, graph

I'm willing to use [ploticus](http://ploticus.sourceforge.net/) (mostly for basic graph) ; yet I don't if it's still working out the box for macos (m1) since I have not been able yet to get relevant information ; if still working, I can install it with homebrew, but then I dont know how to put the pl command in the path (for myself as user). Does anyone have knowledge to share ?

Answer (score 2):

[Ploticus is supplied by homebrew.](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ploticus)

You will be guided to fixing your path before you even install this. I would run through the homebrew installer and then check with `brew doctor` to validate your path.

Then

```
brew install ploticus
```